# How to make a simple upvote/downvote system (vuejs/firebase)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Hello and excuse me if the question is too obvious, but I'm starting with this and freaking out.

I try that a user can vote and remove his vote from an item posted by another user on the same button, basically looking for a functionality like the fav of twitter, I have managed to make it vote, but I'm not succeeding with removing the vote.

The code part with the upvote (at least it works for me) is the following:

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
const fb = require('../firebaseConfig.js')

export default {
    computed: {
        ...mapState(['userProfile', 'currentUser', 'items'])
    },
    methods: {
        upvoteItem(itemId, itemUpvotes) {
            let docId = `${this.currentUser.uid}_${itemId}`
            fb.upvotesCollection.doc(docId).get().then(doc => {
                if (doc.exists) { return }
                fb.upvotesCollection.doc(docId).set({
                    itemId: itemId,
                    userId: this.currentUser.uid
                }).then(() => {
                    // actualizar item upvotes
                    fb.itemsCollection.doc(itemId).update({
                        upvotes: itemUpvotes + 1,
                    })
                })
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
        },
    }
}
```

Then the html to make the upvote (and show the counter):

```
<button @click="upvoteItem(item.id, item.upvotes)">{{ item.upvotes }}</button>
```

Any ideas for moving forward?

Comment: You should most probably used a transaction in your code, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions. In order to downvote why don't you do `.update({
                            upvotes: itemUpvotes - 1,
                        })` after having checked that `upvotes` values is > 1??

Comment: Using transaction is the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to do it as recommended, but I haven't been able to do it well.

However, I have tried to think of alternative ways of doing it.

I found this one interesting (even though it probably doesn't make sense, for some reason I don't know).

1) added "upvoted: false" to the item when created

2) added two methods (one for vote, another for downvote)

```
methods: {
            upvoteItem(itemId, upvotes) {
                let docId = `${this.currentUser.uid}_${itemId}`
                fb.upvotesCollection.doc(docId).get().then(doc => {
                    if (doc.exists) { return }
                    fb.upvotesCollection.doc(docId).set({
                        itemId: itemId,
                        userId: this.currentUser.uid
                    }).then(() => {
                        fb.itemsCollection.doc(itemId).update({
                            upvotes: upvotes + 1,
                            upvoted: false
                        })
                    })
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
            },
            downvoteItem(itemId, upvotes) {
                let docId = `${this.currentUser.uid}_${itemId}`
                fb.upvotesCollection.doc(docId).get().then(doc => {
                    if (doc.exists) { return }
                    fb.upvotesCollection.doc(docId).set({
                        itemId: itemId,
                        userId: this.currentUser.uid
                    }).then(() => {
                        fb.itemCollection.doc(itemId).update({
                            upvotes: upvotes - 1,
                            upvoted: true
                        })
                    })
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
            },
```

3) ternary operator on-click

```
<button @click="item.upvoted ? downvoteItem(item.id, item.upvotes) : upvoteItem(item.id, item.upvotes)">{{ item.upvotes }}</button>
```

But the ternary operator only works with the first click, I can't get the second one to work!